# Connecting 2 monitors to laptop

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have Lenovo thinkpad E530, with:

1. Intel HD Graphics 4000 (Driver 8.15.10.2639)
2. Windows 7 (64 bit)
3. Intel64 Family 6 2095 MHz Processor (Intel Core i7)
4. Built in display connector type LVDS

I have two monitors both VGA connectors.
Connecting one monitor to VGA works well as extended display.

But connecting other VGA monitor on HDMI port (using adapter) doesnt show any display on 2nd external monitor. In control panel I can see the third monitor showing as "Disconnect this display", even if I change that to "Extend this display" it changes back to "Disconnect this display".

In Intel Graphics control panel under display I see only 2 displays (primary and second) there is no third, however in the list of displays i can see the third monitor listed.

How can I get my third display working? And what would this mean in my case:

> 1. If two of the displays are DisplayPort* monitors
> 2. If one of the displays is an Intel® Wireless Display (Intel® WiDi)
> 3. If the built-in display is an Embedded DisplayPort1 (eDP)

Comment: I'm unsure why you've written the last part - does your laptop support DisplayPort, Intel WiDi or eDP? From your description you only have VGA and HDMI... I think you'll only ever be able to use (at most) one of the external connections at any one time. I.e. Laptop + VGA OR Laptop + HDMI. If your laptop had a DisplayPort then things may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely two snags to the setup you're trying to achieve:

1. The problem you're running into with that "HDMI port being adapted to
   VGA but not working" is that it's only sending digital output, not
   digital and analog (ie; VGA) pins.  So the adapter can't help with
   that as it maps the pins but the card isn't generating the signal in
   your laptop for VGA.
2. Most laptops usually only support one EXTERNAL display at any given
   time.  Especially with a built in Intel chipset, you're likely
   capped at the built in display plus ONE external port at any given
   time.  You may find unplugging the VGA port/monitor causes this other display to work.

So with that in mind take a look at a USB-to-VGA port device.  It's basically a graphics card on a USB dongle, and they make them with various outputs including VGA.  here is a good starting point for these: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100019429&IsNodeId=1&Description=VGA

If you have USB 3.0 definitely get a USB 3.0 adapter, performance will be great/comparable to the built in video card for desktop/application use.

Comment: Thanks that seems the problem, I am in conversation with Lenovo team, who are very slow in their response. Once I get some definitive answer from them, I will update this question.